# Computing the global and Hochschild dimensions of a free product of direct products of fields.

Tags: homological-algebra, algebras, dimension-theory-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field (algebraically closed of characteristic 0, but I do not expect it to make a difference).

Consider the algebra $A=k^{n+1}\ast k^{m+1}$, where $\ast$ denotes the free product of associative algebras. Then $A$ can also be written as a quotient of a free algebra $A=k\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m\rangle/I$, where $I$ is generated by the relations

1. $x_i^2=x_i$, $1\leqslant i\leqslant n;$
2. $y_j^2=y_j$, $1\leqslant j\leqslant m;$
3. $x_ix_j$, $1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n$, $i\neq j$;
4. $y_iy_j$, $1\leqslant i,j\leqslant m$, $i\neq j$.

How would one compute the Hochschild homology and cohomology of $A$? I know that $A$ has left global dimension 1 as a free product of algebras of global dimension 0.

What is the projective dimension of $A$ as an $A$-bimodule? I didn't find the bar resolution suitable for this computation and failed miserably at finding a simpler one.

Comment: years ago I did [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.4110.pdf) which looked at a similar question for augmented algebras via explicit resolutions (the notation unfortunately clashes with yours).  Some of it might be useful to you even if it isn't exactly the situation you are looking at.